# Setting up SSD+HDD Storage Properly

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage

So the other day I purchased a 128gb SSD for my desktop.

Currently I run 12.10 on a SATA drive, but want to do a clean install on the SSD and run that as the main OS drive+apps.

I've been reading everywhere that I should set up a HDD as a 'Storage' drive, for all data *not* going on the SSD. This is logical, and I will be using the 300gb drive I currently do--**but** my question is, is there any way to make that HDD the 'default' save-space for the OS?

What I mean is that, I assume when I install Ubuntu on the SSD it will establish all the folders (docs, pics, videos, downloads &c&c) and will want to--by default--access these whenever I click into them.

Is there a way to set that up on a separate drive and 'default' in to that, rather than the SSD?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a guide for that, a full recording :)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sPGEwqoXA0 also read the description
you probably don't want to make the /var/cache/apt/archives partition i did, doing it made my [desktop boot slower](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2141351)

Comment: Ahh! I am sure that will be very helpful.

Just to be clear--you booted from your USB, installed gParted and then sorted the partitions from there?

So Basically "/" is the OS install, and I would make my storage drive "/home" for the brunt of my documents/pic/video folders &c?

Comment: yep, i also put /var on the hdd to reduce wear on the ssd and i moved /root to /home/root for when i use a app via gksu; btw gparted is pre-installed on a live ubuntu disk

Answer (score 1):

Create the main partition `/` and `swap` on the SSD and `/home` on your HDD.

Comment: if you dont have much ram swap on the ssd will make the system faster, however it will put heavy wear on the ssd shortening the lifespan; i have never see anyone recommend swap on a ssd

Comment: I am happy to put swap on the HDD.

Would it make things better if I put *more* to the swap drive on the HDD rather than less to it on the SSD?

Comment: it depends on your ram capacity and what your gonnna do, for example if you have 4 gigabyte of ram and use your computer just to watch movies or do simple stuff, swap is not important but if you work with blender which needs mush and fast virtual memory then it is important

Comment: Most of the heavy stuff like games I do on an old Windows drive I have in there as well.

This will be for light photo editing, music, videos and every day use.